# Setting property dynamically based on condition and returning the right type

Tags: typescript

I would like to reuse a function in order to transform an array of certain type and return the array of that same type. I have 2 types of objects that only have one field that is different from each other. I can't change those types because they are generate from an api. These 2 types looks like this:

```
export interface ResidencePeriodDto {
    dateFrom?: string;
    dateTo?: string;
    residenceStatus: ResidenceStatusType;
    source: Source;
}
export interface CivilPeriodDto {
    dateFrom?: string;
    dateTo?: string;
    civilStatus: CivilStatusType;
    source: Source;
}


export enum ResidenceStatusType {
    NOT_REGISTERT_AT_ADDRESS = "NOT_REGISTERT_AT_ADDRESS",
    REGISTERT_AT_ADDRESS = "REGISTERT_AT_ADDRESS",
}
export enum CivilStatusType {
    MARRIED = "MARRIED",
    NOT_MARRIED = "NOT_MARRIED",
}
export enum Source {
    PRIVATE = "PRIVATE",
    PUBLIC = "PUBLIC",
}
```

I would like to reuse a function that does the same thing for both types of objects. The only difference is that they have different status fields, so I was thinking I could send a string parameter to the function and set the field dynamically:

```
const testFunc = (period: ResidencePeriodDto | CivilPeriodDto, statusField: "civilStatus" | "residenceStatus"):ResidencePeriodDto | CivilPeriodDto => {
  // some common code for both types of periods
  // that would return either ResidencePeriodDto or CivilPeriodDto based on the statusField param
  
  return {
    dateFrom: "01.01.2023",
    dateTo: "31.12.2023",
    [statusField]: statusField === "civilStatus" ? CivilStatusType.NOT_MARRIED : ResidenceStatusType.NOT_REGISTERT_AT_ADDRESS,
    source: Source.PRIVATE
  }
}
```

But, if I do that I get typescript error:

```
Type '{ [x: string]: string; dateFrom: string; dateTo: string; source: Source.PRIVATE; }' is not assignable to type 'ResidencePeriodDto | CivilPeriodDto'.
  Property 'civilStatus' is missing in type '{ [x: string]: string; dateFrom: string; dateTo: string; source: Source.PRIVATE; }' but required in type 'CivilPeriodDto'.
```

How could I achieve something like this?

Here is the [link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=33&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBMAdgVwLZwErAM4EsAmSAxsAMowCGMy2AKgJ5jBwDeAUHJ3AHIDytAfQwBRAOIBJUrWEZBAQXkARRSNKk4AXjgAiPoJESpM%20UpXC12gDQcuBydNkCFT5avVbtdo4%20dzX50is2AF82UEhYBBR0AGFcADdcABtyKhoGJlYbTgBZOQwMcWFFTR08gqLFIK4efgFywuLS3TqGyqDQ8Oh4JDQ4UghkKBIsmoAFQoA1BWFmifFp6WquMYBVACEAGXEYuY3tmI6w8G64XEQYYCgAMwoRrDxCRBIxq9wIfEUYCFGufCpgAAxKAQVAAfgAXHBsDAoOcAOYAbmycH%20l1oEEh0NhCORNSgOAIxDIlGo2ChDyJzxJaTojGAeK42EGw2AUIGQxIyM6J0i50uNzuzDiiSSrzhHy%20P3YNTRQJB4KhMLhiCRKLlGKxytxKKICWSqTJUJFBtJ6XpjM4zM5bP6LK5ITYbCIEEQMLglxhgOQz1KAAomBL8BTCU8Xm9Jd84AAfOAmsURz7fSzY2mA3DAJLBnR60WGmjaGM6AmPYn57DaACUEMpYeA4veSZ%20sfjDcjPw0AD5fgTqFBEL9OHLgaCodoAAwARgAdFPpwAmcfzgDMyyHAIxY%20XM8n84XS9X1hqAG0YWmM1mALpKs3YdOZ-CaDQeXOm2mFsFx-UpW8ZYDTvR6nyRoShDUtqXLP8ALqLwHBMFwzDUI8mXtW0OVZad5kWYQbFCYIgA) to typescript playground where I have setup the example from the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Function overloading is probably the way to go here as TS has a (very frustrating) limitation whereby you can't infer the return type from an argument without explicitly defining the overloads like this.

The advantage though is that you will get the same type as the one that was passed in dynamically.

```
export interface ResidencePeriodDto {
    dateFrom?: string;
    dateTo?: string;
    residenceStatus: ResidenceStatusType;
    source: Source;
}
export interface CivilPeriodDto {
    dateFrom?: string;
    dateTo?: string;
    civilStatus: CivilStatusType;
    source: Source;
}


export enum ResidenceStatusType {
    NOT_REGISTERT_AT_ADDRESS = "NOT_REGISTERT_AT_ADDRESS",
    REGISTERT_AT_ADDRESS = "REGISTERT_AT_ADDRESS",
}
export enum CivilStatusType {
    MARRIED = "MARRIED",
    NOT_MARRIED = "NOT_MARRIED",
}
export enum Source {
    PRIVATE = "PRIVATE",
    PUBLIC = "PUBLIC",
}

const isResidencePeriod = (period: CivilPeriodDto | ResidencePeriodDto): period is ResidencePeriodDto => period.hasOwnProperty('residenceStatus')


function testFunc(period: ResidencePeriodDto): ResidencePeriodDto
function testFunc(period: CivilPeriodDto): CivilPeriodDto
function testFunc(period: CivilPeriodDto | ResidencePeriodDto) {
  if (isResidencePeriod(period)) {
    return {
      ...period,
      residenceStatus: ResidenceStatusType.NOT_REGISTERT_AT_ADDRESS
    }
  }

  return {
    ...period,
    civilStatus: CivilStatusType.NOT_MARRIED 
  }
}

const test1 = testFunc({residenceStatus: ResidenceStatusType.REGISTERT_AT_ADDRESS, source: Source.PRIVATE, dateFrom: '123213', dateTo: '12124'}) // Test1 will be correctly typed as ResidencePeriodDto
const test2 = testFunc({civilStatus: CivilStatusType.MARRIED, source: Source.PRIVATE, dateFrom: '123213', dateTo: '12124'})  // Test2 will be correctly typed as CivilPeriodDto
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I do have a follow up question to this one. I wonder why this code won't work if we use lists or arrays as types? Here is the question: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77505136/setting-property-dynamically-based-on-condition-and-returning-the-right-type-wor

Answer (score 0):

While theoretically your code should work, it seems that TS needs to infer the exact key to match the property correctly and cast it to the return value.

You can do this by just returning two objects based on an if statement:

```
const testFunc1 = (period: ResidencePeriodDto | CivilPeriodDto, statusField: "civilStatus" | "residenceStatus"): ResidencePeriodDto | CivilPeriodDto => {
  if (statusField === "civilStatus") {
    return {
        dateFrom: "01.01.2023",
        dateTo: "31.12.2023",
        [statusField]: CivilStatusType.NOT_MARRIED,
        source: Source.PRIVATE
    }
  }
  return {
    dateFrom: "01.01.2023",
    dateTo: "31.12.2023",
    [statusField]: ResidenceStatusType.NOT_REGISTERT_AT_ADDRESS,
    source: Source.PRIVATE
  }
}
```

Or, if you want to keep it short, you can move the ternary condition one step above so that TS knows both the key and value in the scope of the ternary. You do need to construct an additional object that you will spread/assign to the return value:

```
const testFunc2 = (period: ResidencePeriodDto | CivilPeriodDto, statusField: "civilStatus" | "residenceStatus"): ResidencePeriodDto | CivilPeriodDto => {
  return {
    dateFrom: "01.01.2023",
    dateTo: "31.12.2023",
    ...(statusField === "civilStatus"
        ? { [statusField]: CivilStatusType.NOT_MARRIED }
        : { [statusField]: ResidenceStatusType.NOT_REGISTERT_AT_ADDRESS }
    ),
    source: Source.PRIVATE
  }
}
```

Comment: Note this will return `ResidencePeriodDto | CivilPeriodDto` instead of the one that was passed in (he might not care though).

Comment: Agreed, I didn't want to modify that part as it is not part of the question, but using a function overload or constrained generic `<T extends ResidencePeriodDto | CivilPeriodDto` would be a good improvement on type safety.

Comment: Yeh I tried the latter as well but you get into all sorts of hell around extra properties being allowed (and it doesn't resolve the return type thing either cos of really annoying ts limitations).

Comment: Yeah, the generic seems to require an `as T` cast at the end to work properly because of the whole "but this can maybe be something else" which defeats the purpose because a cast was always an option.

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to reuse a function that does the same thing for both types of objects. The only difference is that they have different status fields, so I was thinking I could send a string parameter to the function and set the field dynamically:

It seems weird that the function knows the field value, but requires the field name to be passed in. So either I'd pass in both:

```
type PeriodDto = {
    dateFrom?: string,
    dateTo?: string,
    source: Source,
}

const testFunc = <T extends object>(period: PeriodDto & T, t: T): PeriodDto & T => {
  return {
    dateFrom: "01.01.2023",
    dateTo: "31.12.2023",
    source: Source.PRIVATE,
    ...t,
  }
}

const residencePeriod = {} as ResidencePeriodDto;
const y = testFunc(residencePeriod, {residenceStatus: ResidenceStatusType.NOT_REGISTERT_AT_ADDRESS});
```

or neither

```
function testFunc2(period: ResidencePeriodDto): ResidencePeriodDto;
function testFunc2(period: CivilPeriodDto): CivilPeriodDto;
function testFunc2(period: ResidencePeriodDto | CivilPeriodDto): ResidencePeriodDto | CivilPeriodDto {
  return {
    dateFrom: "01.01.2023",
    dateTo: "31.12.2023",
    source: Source.PRIVATE,
    ...("residenceStatus" in period) ? {residenceStatus: ResidenceStatusType.NOT_REGISTERT_AT_ADDRESS} : {civilStatus: CivilStatusType.NOT_MARRIED}
  }
}

const y2 = testFunc(residencePeriod);
```

The first solution uses [generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html), [intersection types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types), and the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax). The second solution uses [function overloads](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads), the `in` operator to [narrow](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html) the type, and the spread operator to copy the properties.

Comment: I have a follow up question to this one, because I wonder why this code is failing when arrays are being used:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77505136/setting-property-dynamically-based-on-condition-and-returning-the-right-type-wor