# Setting property dynamically based on condition and returning the right type works for single object, but not for lists

Tags: typescript

I have a follow question for a question that was answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77504329/setting-property-dynamically-based-on-condition-and-returning-the-right-type). I wonder why the answer works when there are single objects sent as a parameter to function, but not when there are arrays:

```
export enum ResidenceStatusType {
    NOT_REGISTERT_AT_ADDRESS = "NOT_REGISTERT_AT_ADDRESS",
    REGISTERT_AT_ADDRESS = "REGISTERT_AT_ADDRESS",
}
export enum CivilStatusType {
    MARRIED = "MARRIED",
    NOT_MARRIED = "NOT_MARRIED",
}
export enum Source {
    PRIVATE = "PRIVATE",
    PUBLIC = "PUBLIC",
}
export interface ResidencePeriodDto {
    dateFrom?: string;
    dateTo?: string;
    residenceStatus: ResidenceStatusType;
    source: Source;
}
export interface CivilPeriodDto {
    dateFrom?: string;
    dateTo?: string;
    civilStatus: CivilStatusType;
    source: Source;
}

const isResidencePeriod = (periods: CivilPeriodDto | ResidencePeriodDto): periods is ResidencePeriodDto => periods.hasOwnProperty('residenceStatus')

function testFunc(periods: ResidencePeriodDto[]): ResidencePeriodDto[]
function testFunc(periods: CivilPeriodDto[]): CivilPeriodDto[]
function testFunc(periods: ResidencePeriodDto[] | CivilPeriodDto[]): ResidencePeriodDto[] | CivilPeriodDto[] {
  return [{
    dateFrom: "01.01.2023",
    dateTo: "31.12.2023",
    ...("residenceStatus" in periods
        ? { residenceStatus: ResidenceStatusType.NOT_REGISTERT_AT_ADDRESS  }
        : { civilStatus: CivilStatusType.MARRIED }
    ),
    source: Source.PRIVATE
  }]
}

const civilPeriod = [{
    dateFrom: "01.01.2023",
    dateTo: "31.12.2023",
    civilStatus: CivilStatusType.MARRIED,
    source: Source.PRIVATE
}]

const residencePeriod = [{
    dateFrom: "01.01.2023",
    dateTo: "31.12.2023",
    residenceStatus: ResidenceStatusType.NOT_REGISTERT_AT_ADDRESS,
    source: Source.PRIVATE
}]

testFunc(civilPeriod)
testFunc(residencePeriod)
```

So, for this code I get an error:

```
Type '({ source: Source.PRIVATE; residenceStatus: ResidenceStatusType.NOT_REGISTERT_AT_ADDRESS; dateFrom: string; dateTo: string; } | { source: Source.PRIVATE; civilStatus: CivilStatusType.MARRIED; dateFrom: string; dateTo: string; })[]' is not assignable to type 'ResidencePeriodDto[] | CivilPeriodDto[]'.
  Type '({ source: Source.PRIVATE; residenceStatus: ResidenceStatusType.NOT_REGISTERT_AT_ADDRESS; dateFrom: string; dateTo: string; } | { source: Source.PRIVATE; civilStatus: CivilStatusType.MARRIED; dateFrom: string; dateTo: string; })[]' is not assignable to type 'ResidencePeriodDto[]'.
    Type '{ source: Source.PRIVATE; residenceStatus: ResidenceStatusType.NOT_REGISTERT_AT_ADDRESS; dateFrom: string; dateTo: string; } | { source: Source.PRIVATE; civilStatus: CivilStatusType.MARRIED; dateFrom: string; dateTo: string; }' is not assignable to type 'ResidencePeriodDto'.
      Property 'residenceStatus' is missing in type '{ source: Source.PRIVATE; civilStatus: CivilStatusType.MARRIED; dateFrom: string; dateTo: string; }' but required in type 'ResidencePeriodDto'.
```

Here is the [link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-PUw00Ltpp3XZDPGDvRBwS4wwFjoiByOhr0FyNSgDaAF0M3mqT7gxvN2xR+PJ9OcDA589F8HQ+HC6mtzv72vvlvj-OJ67z7P5zfsxSCargeb6brGYb6hGIEQE+gF9vuKaHuBL7QVuvwEtQUBTuuMp-ACwKglC2gAAwAIxVmRVYAEzEVRADMyycBqEBEXR5GkVR1G0Qx1g1FW-H+tovZ7jSZLaGcU4ViGKI1GCrBwMJiYDsuQH9madJMFWehCGI9jGE4phuJwoQ1DUUIsHAeqispxqQcpGTAFWbRNCZXBprxTL2raHKslW8yLMINjBEeoTOq67pWckD6lDh6r4QqRGUZRNH0YxqIAhirHsZxKU8bqdnqbZ1nqQ5Tn5I0igeVaXnsl5flTDMIRHmFbrwIpwEpjFuFMfFhE6El5G5WlzFZVWHFcalVUKapJA2buSklfSWl1F4DgmC4ZhqFN1qsrVNr1QsjXBU6M6Xn+kVQSmw6nVeC7tdSD5pkAA) to typescript playground where I have setup the example from the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `periods`, being an array, never has a `residenceStatus` property. The test `"residenceStatus" in periods` therefore does not reveal whether `periods` is an array of `ResidencePeriodDto` or of `CivilPeriodDto`. You should probably test whether `"residenceStatus" in periods[0]`.

Then, you still get a rather cryptic message. To investigate why, let's introduce a temporary variable:

```
  const r = [{
    dateFrom: "01.01.2023",
    dateTo: "31.12.2023",
    ...("residenceStatus" in periods
        ? { residenceStatus: ResidenceStatusType.NOT_REGISTERT_AT_ADDRESS  }
        : { civilStatus: CivilStatusType.MARRIED }
    ),
    source: Source.PRIVATE
  }];
  return r;
```

and inspect its inferred type by hovering over its declaration:

```
const r: ({
    source: Source;
    residenceStatus: ResidenceStatusType;
    dateFrom: string;
    dateTo: string;
} | {
    source: Source;
    civilStatus: CivilStatusType;
    dateFrom: string;
    dateTo: string;
})[]
```

That is, the compiler inferred a type of `(ResidencePeriodDto | CivilPeriodDto)[]` rather than `ResidencePeriodDto[] | CivilPeriodDto[]` - and since the former is not assignable to the latter (an array containing both apples and oranges is neither an array of apples nor an array of oranges ...), you get the compiler error. To help the compiler out, you can create separate arrays in these cases:

```
function testFunc(periods: ResidencePeriodDto[]): ResidencePeriodDto[]
function testFunc(periods: CivilPeriodDto[]): CivilPeriodDto[]
function testFunc(periods: ResidencePeriodDto[] | CivilPeriodDto[]): ResidencePeriodDto[] | CivilPeriodDto[] {
  const period = {
    dateFrom: "01.01.2023",
    dateTo: "31.12.2023",
    source: Source.PRIVATE,
  }
  return "residenceStatus" in periods[0]
        ? [{...period, residenceStatus: ResidenceStatusType.NOT_REGISTERT_AT_ADDRESS }]
        : [{...period, civilStatus: CivilStatusType.MARRIED }]
}
```